# Convert And deploy an Existing App challenge

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, trailhead

I am stuck in completing this last part of Salesforce DX challenge.

I have 2 issues. The first one i did not realise when that happened but its there. Its in the image below with JSON. file. I dont know when this happened and how i could resolve it.[image]

and Number 2 is that i dont understand which TP are we being told to log into here and creating which alias? please see the image below

[image]

because i cant log into right ORG thats why i am unable to complete the 3 step of next part (see image below)

[image]

please advise me on these issue so i can finish my challange.

Looking forward for help

thank you

Answer (score 1):

## Part 1

Remove sfdx force:org:list from the JSON file. It should start with { and end with }.

## Part 2

Type in sfdx commands into the Terminal. You can open the Terminal with Ctrl+Shift+~. It appears in the bottom right side of the window. You can see it in your first screenshot where it currently says PROBLEMS (1). You can also click TERMINAL to start a new Terminal.

## Part 3

You can type in sfdx force:org:list in the Terminal to see the aliases set and the orgs you are logged in to. Further commands should also be entered in to the Terminal, unless instructed otherwise.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying

Comment: i have not added anything manually and all the codes i have been putting as per instructed in the challenge..could you please make chage in the above code so i know excatly how i could insert to resolve JSON. file error.  Much appreciated

Comment: " sfdx force:org:list{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "46.0"
}
"

Comment: @zsk_1 please remove everything up to the initial {. The file should start with { and end with }. Everything inside appears to be correct.

Comment: would you be able to help me with the problem i have posted in this link?

Answer (score 0):

i made the changes for solution number 1 which worked fine however for Part 2) i am getting this error...can anyone advise please?

[image]